# let G_n be the graph whose vertices are all binary string of length n

Tags: graph-theory

For any positive integer n,  let G_n be the graph whose vertices are all binary string of length n that have precisely two block of 1's,  each of which is of length at most 3,  and two vertices are adjacent if and only if the corresponding strings differ in exactly one position.  determine the number of vertices in G_n and edges in G_n

I couldn't understand how to create this graph. Anyone please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment but:

**`n<3`**

There are no binary strings with precisely two blocks of ones so `G_0`, `G_1` and `G_2` all have zero vertices and edges.

**`n=3`**

There is one binary string with precisely two blocks of ones - the string `101`.

So `G_3` has one vertex and zero edges.

**`n=4`**

There are five binary strings with two blocks of ones:

```
A. 0101
B. 1001
C. 1011
D. 1101
E. 1010
```

You can find whether there is an edge using the simple method of `XOR`ing two binary numbers and if the result has exactly one bit set then there exists an edge.

```
0101 XOR 1001 = 1100 => No edge between A and B
0101 XOR 1011 = 1110 => No edge between A and C
0101 XOR 1101 = 1000 => Edge between A and D
0101 XOR 1010 = 1111 => No edge between A and E
1001 XOR 1011 = 0010 => Edge between B and C
1001 XOR 1101 = 0100 => Edge between B and D
1001 XOR 1010 = 0011 => No edge between B and E
1011 XOR 1101 = 0110 => No edge between C and D
1011 XOR 1010 = 0001 => Edge between C and E
1101 XOR 1010 = 0110 => No edge between D and E
```

So there are 5 vertices and 4 edges.

**Repeat until you see a pattern**